# Remove element in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, stop-words

I Have stopwords arraylist.. I Want to remove arraylist element (String) that contain stopwords.

Here's arraylist1 that i want to remove elements:

```
bicara
dunia
penerbangan
orang
sering
salah
menjawab
bila
ditanya
siapa
manusia
pertama
yang
mengudara
mayoritas
menjawab
oliver
wilber
wright
dari
amerika
serikat
yang
terbang
pada
tahun
padahal
```

Here's stopwords:

```
dari
bila
ditanya
menjawab
pada
padahal
pertama
siapa
sering
tahun
yang
```

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.size(); j++) {
        if (stopwords.get(j).equals(arraylist1.get(i)))
            arraylist1.remove(i);
    }
}
```

But the result does not match what I want:

```
bicara
dunia
penerbangan
orang
salah 
bila (not removed)
manusia
mengudara
mayoritas
oliver
wilber
wright
amerika
serikat
terbang
padahal (not removed)
```

Comment: Read the difference between [remove(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) & [remove(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not look at every *element* of the list, you look at every *index* of the list. If you remove an element, the elements following that element will be shifted forward, changing their index. If a stopword is followed by another stopword, the second one is ignored.

If you want to fix your solution, you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.size(); j++) {
        if (stopwords.get(j).equals(arraylist1.get(i))) {
            arraylist1.remove(i);
            i--; // you have to look at the same index again!
        }
    }
}
```

However, it is better to use the methods provided by the Java API:

```
arraylist1.removeAll(stopwords);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way to do it (assuming there are no duplicates in your original list) :

```
    for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.size(); j++) {
        arraylist1.remove(stopwords.get(j));
    }
```

or better (this will work even if there are duplicates) :

```
    arraylist1.removeAll(stopwords);
```